# IOS CoreImage Facial Detection at All Orientations

Tags: ios, core-image

I am using `CoreImage` on IOS to detect faces in an image. It works fine when there are multiple faces, but doesn't work for simple faces such as this one:

[image]

The face is really big and obvious, but `CoreImage` cannot detect it.
I'm thinking it may be because of my `kCGImagePropertyOrientation`.

I set it to 5, simply because that's what an online tutorial did.
However, the images which I am processing are user uploaded, so I do not know the orientation of the face beforehand.
Is there a way to try all orientations?
What is the proper way of implementing `CoreImage` facial detection when the images are not known before hand?

This is my code:

```
var imageOptions = Dictionary<String,Any>()
imageOptions[CIDetectorImageOrientation] = 5
imageOptions[CIDetectorSmile] = true

let image = CIImage(cgImage: imageView.image!.cgImage!)
let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]

let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy)
let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: image, options: imageOptions as? [String : AnyObject])
```

Comment: The face detection will only work for the specified orientation, if you want to allow any kind of orientations to be processed you might have to read the orientation from the image metadata itself, then pass that orientation to your filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
   var imageOrienttion = 0
   switch (YourUIImage.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientation.up:
        imageOrienttion = 1
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.down:
        imageOrienttion = 3
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.left:
        imageOrienttion = 8
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.right:
        imageOrienttion = 6
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.upMirrored:
        imageOrienttion = 2
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
        imageOrienttion = 4
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
        imageOrienttion = 5
        break;
    case UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
        imageOrienttion = 7
        break;
   }
   imageOptions[CIDetectorImageOrientation] = imageOrienttion
```

Comment: The image is user uploaded. This code looks like it is reading the image meta-data. My question is, can IOS get the UIImageOrientation for every single image? Even user-uploaded ones?

Comment: iOS should be able to determine orientation. You can just try this code and see if it's work. Or you can just loop through all values until you will be able to find a face.